# Data association no tag why?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I have noticed that there is no tag for data association which is considered as a central point in localization and slam problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking tags are created as the need for them is identified.

If you link to some questions which would benefit from the tag, I would be happy to create the tag and tag those questions with it.

Comment: I've asked this question long time ago about data association this is the link http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/data-association-with-ekf In the aforementioned link, the algorithm for data association is known as Nearest Neighborhood. There are numerous algorithms for data association, a topic that deserves a great attention to construct SLAM.

Comment: If there is a tag, definitely there will be a lot of questions.

Comment: It doesn't work like that CroCo, having a tag doesn't create the questions which require it. Having questions which require a tag causes the tag to be created.

Comment: Actually, you already have the [tag creation privilege](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), so you could have added the [tag:data-association] tag yourself. Please consider adding a tag wiki to explain what this tag is for. Thanks,