# Consideration of "Soft Robotics" tag in Robotics.SE

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

As I would like to ask a question, is which related to the **Soft Robotics**, one would contend that the existence of such tag (with due attention to considerable activities in this field of robotics) could be helpful.

***Don't you think it better to consider this tag within the tag set?!***

Answer (score 3):

As [I said here](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/248/37), generally speaking tags are created as questions which require them are created.

The poster of that similar question said in a comment

> If there is a tag, definitely there will be a lot of questions.

Yet almost 2 years later there are only 3 questions with the [data-association](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-association) tag, which lends weight to my reply of

> It doesn't work like that ..., having a tag doesn't create the questions which require it. Having questions which require a tag causes the tag to be created.

For now though, if you link to some questions which would benefit from the tag, I would be happy to create it. Even better, if you suggest a suitable tag wiki, explaining what it is for, we can ensure that tagging is consistent across questions. As it is, I'm not sure quite what you mean by 'soft' robotics.

Eventually though, you will have enough reputation to gain the [tag creation privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) and then you will be able to create tags simply by adding the new tag to a question you have written.

I noticed [a question from 2015](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/7311/37) which would benefit from the [soft-robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-robotics) tag, so I have created it.

Comment: "Soft Robotics" is the field of the design, manufacturing and control of robots, made from smart materials and soft matters. You can check one aspect of its vibrant community here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj395G09aTMAhVDKywKHRdvDBAQFghYMAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ieee-ras.org%2Fsoft-robotics&usg=AFQjCNEMJ80KZSsrJ-0oLgq_LhvAekPZaw&sig2=g_Lesx6vB5vOKSCbmUT4cA&bvm=bv.119745492,d.bGg. Lack of related tags will lead to complaints from users and moderators.

Comment: As I said, if you can point to even one example of a question for which a *soft robotics* tag would be appropriate, then I can create the tag. Without even a single question, I can't justify creating the tag. Stack Exchange isn't "Field of Dreams", if I create the tag, questions won't magically appear out of nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask questions about soft robotics (or any other robotics related question) on this site with or without a tag for it.

Start asking questions now, tag them later.